# How to invalidate session from Edge with Java?

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, logout

I have a web application with Oauth2 security, and my logout is working perfectly with Chrome and Mozilla, but it doesn't want to log-out with Edge.

When I compare the sessions (*the one in the Edge browser and the one which I receive from HttpServletRequest in the application and invalidate*), they are not the same.

How is that possible?

I guess that's why logout is not working, I am not invalidating the good session, but which session Edge is sending then? How can I log-out?

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session != null) {
  session.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Interesting topic, could you give us more details?

Comment: It is done with using Spring Security functionality logout(). More can be found here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-logout